# button deselect not splicing data out of json object

Tags: angularjs

I have rows of button pairs that are created with `ng-repeat`. When a button in each row is clicked, it changes color (green) to show that it has been toggled and data associated with the button is pushed into a json object array. I also have a function that removes the object from the array. What I want to happen is if the other button in the row is pressed, not only will the data in the json array be removed, but the data in THAT button loaded in its place. So far I'm having trouble making that work.

HTML:

```
<div class="form-horizontal"
data-ng-repeat="item in event.Events track by $index">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button"
        class="btn form-control"
        data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 1 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
        data-ng-click="buttonToggle($index, 1); makePick(item.EventId, event.MemberId, item.AwayId)">
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
        <button type="button"
        class="btn form-control"
        data-ng-class="[pickChosen == 2 ? 'btn-success' : 'btn-default']"
        data-ng-click="buttonToggle($index, 2); makePick(item.EventId, event.MemberId, item.HomeId)">
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Angular:

```
var picks = $scope.picks = [];

$scope.buttonToggle = function(index, buttonNumber) {
        this.pickChosen = buttonNumber === this.pickChosen ? 0 &
        $scope.removePick(index) : buttonNumber;
    };

$scope.makePick = function (eventId, memberId, teamId) {
        picks.push({ "EventId": eventId, "MemberId": memberId, "TeamId": teamId });
    };

    $scope.removePick = function(index) {
        picks.splice(index, 1);
```

Right now as it stands, if I click a different button, the new object is added to the array, but the old one isn't deleted. I wonder if anyone can help with a solution. Thanks.